# Mariadb non-root user

Tags: mysql, root, mariadb

I have installed mariadb and when as a Linux root user, I can run mysql command to access the database. But when I try to login as a normal Linux user and run `mysql -u root -p`, I am getting error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.
```

I tried several methods like reset password for the mysql root user, but no use.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448404/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was caused by a "plugin" value in "mysql.user" table.

Have you tried with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/636579/299538

Here is an explanation for that: https://superuser.com/a/1071043/592085

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB you cannot login with normal user, you must root access or use `sudo`. Another solution add another root user with full privileges.

Connect with sudo to db:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Check your account in present db:

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | localhost |
```

Recreate user `root` (use password if you need):

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

Give permission:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Flush:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Show database uses:

```
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------+-----------+
| User | Host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | %         |
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
```

Exit and connect with normal user:

```
mysql -u root
```