# Ubuntu Server MySQL access denied problem

Tags: server, mysql

I started working a bit on an assignment. I setup Ubuntu Server (latest version) and installed apache2 which works but also MySQL. I used:

```
apt-get -y install mariadb-server
```

Then I did

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

I setup my root password. I rebooted the server and I tried to login with my normal user (so not my root user) on MySQL. However, if I use my password, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I don't understand what's wrong. I tried doing the installation multiple times.

How I tried to login to MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then I inserted my password.

Comment: Edit your question and include how you tried to connect to mysql, blank out your password XXXX.

Comment: Added it. Also, no need to blank out my password as it's basically invisible :p

Comment: Is this relevant to you?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/448404/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y

Comment: @bc2946088 Yea, that fixed it. Thanks.